# Where did Poe get another black X-Wing?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

A mildly whimsical question:

After losing his X-Wing on Jakku, how did Poe get (another?) black one?

I mean in the sense of priorities. Was there some sort of dialog with the officer on duty on the flight line:

> Officer: Glad to see you've recovered from all that torture, Poe. Here's your new X-Wing.
>
> Poe: That's not mine. It's the wrong colour.
>
> Officer: What?
>
> Poe: It's not black.
>
> Officer: Uhm, you and your squadron need to take off at once, we got word that BB-8 needs rescuing right now.
>
> Poe: Sorry, I want it repainted.
>
> Officer: Now?! The galaxy depends on you.
>
> Poe: I save the galaxy in style or not at all.
>
> Officer: < breaks down and sobs>

Why was this **obviously** canonical scene deleted, I ask?

Or do they have buckets of black paint standing around to spray on whichever X-Wing Poe needs to hop into?

**To make this question a bit more earnest: while it's hard to see in the low light on Jakku, was that X-Wing also a black one? I don't have image-by-image capabilities to drill into that well enough. Does somebody have the ability to show a shot that clearly shows the colour, one way or another?**

Comment: PS: what happens to paint that hasn't dried when you jump to lightspeed?!

Comment: Thanks for reinforcing my view of Poe Dameron as Ace Rimmer. Smoke me a kipper, commander.

Comment: This gazpacho is cold!

Comment: It's not paint - they've got high-tech chameleon coating that can change to the whim of the pilot.  You just hit Triangle on the load screen until you get the color you want.

Comment: And if Apple made X-WIngs, the most desirable colour would always be in rare supply and cost twice as much on Ebay. ;)

Comment: Where's Quentin Tarantino when you need him?  "You get four guys fighting over who's gonna be Black Leader. Since nobody knows anybody else, nobody wants to back down. So forget it, I pick."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The X-wing that Poe used on Jakku was in the Resistance's standard blue-and-white colors. It wasn't his personal black X-wing.

This is most visible in one of the photos that [Annie Leibovitz shot for Vanity Fair](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/05/star-wars-force-awakens-photos), in which Oscar Isaac is seen in costume hanging off the side of a blue-and-white X-wing in the desert:

[image]

The color scheme is also fairly clear in stills from the film, but it's very clear in this shot from [an early behind-the-scenes feature](http://www.slashfilm.com/force-awakens-behind-the-scenes/2/), in which Isaac is seen performing alongside the X-wing prop:

[image]

Comment: I think I love you! So, he used a spare one, instead of his usual black model. Probably worried about what the Jakku sand would do to his precious paint job.

Comment: Do you have references for "_It wasn't his personal black X-Wing_"?  While I can understand owning your own X-Wing, there are other possible sources for the ship (like maybe a new, top of the line model or style for the best pilot in the resistance after a particularly difficult mission).

Comment: @Trisped The word "personal" does not inherently have a connotation of ownership. It is here being used to mean "intended for use by one person", and to indicate that he's the only one with a variant color on his fighter.

Comment: @Marakai Considering that this mission was almost certainly covert, taking his distinctly painted X-Wing would have been a dead giveaway that he was there

Comment: @Machavity Good point!

Comment: @Machavity And taking his X-Wing painted in resistance colors was not? (Separate comment)  The black X-Wing is probably how the fighter was painted in the factory and they did not have time to paint it.

Comment: @Trisped If you're on a covert mission you'd want them to think "low level peon" instead of "Black Squadron Leader" or "Leia's right-hand man". And [according to Starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/resistance-x-wing), Poe's black X-Wing is customized for him

Comment: @Machavity If I was on a covert mission, I would want them to think "Merchant/Smuggler", not "low level enemy".  Your link says "During the [movie detail removed], Poe Dameron flies a customized, dark-hulled X-wing under the call sign Black Leader."  It does not say that it is Poe's, nor does it say if it is customized in any way more than its coloring.  It does mention " The credit-strapped Resistance relies on X-wings donated or lent by sympathetic New Republic senators and local security forces.", so a replacement fighter in non-standard colors might have been donated.